# How to insert a time-zoned converted Timestamp into a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I set my timestamp to a specific time zone, particularly US/Pacific?

Consider this MWE:

```
CREATE TABLE #timingTable (theTime datetime2(0))

INSERT INTO #timingTable 
    SELECT (SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);

SELECT * FROM #timingTable;
```

Comment: `datetime2` doesn't store timezone information, you need a `datetimeoffset`

Comment: Whats a "MWE" BTW?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SYSDATETIMEOFFSET to get the current time with the offset, and then use AT TIME ZONE to convert it to the timezone you want the datetime stored in.

```
CREATE TABLE #timingTable (theTime datetime2(0))

INSERT INTO #timingTable SELECT SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time';

select * from #timingTable;
```

Comment: You won't be able to retrieve the timezone again once stored though?

Comment: No `datetime2` lacks time zone information.  Even `datetimeoffset` lacks time zone; it only has the offset, which could be from more than one time zone.

Comment: Personally, I default to using *datetimeoffset* as the type for any date-time column and determine the local time on the client.  So I would never do the above, but I don't know the OPs use-case.

Answer (score -2):

```
(SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time');
```

I would read [these docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/at-time-zone-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and see if it helps clarify.

Comment: That doesn't work see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=695ca2950309f000934dafed2cf9fd3f)